# How to set internal Enum for particular value?

Tags: c#, enums, access-modifiers

I want to have `enum` as `public` but one of the `enum` value should be `internal`. Is this possible in C#?

```
public enum Numbers
{
      One,
      Two,
      Three,
      internal Zero // I want zero as internal
}
```

Comment: What should happen when external code reads the value `Numbers.Zero`?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Numbers.Zero should not be accessible outside namespace

Comment: But what does that mean? Assume you have a field `class Foo { public Numbers numbers = Numbers.Zero; }` What should happen if someone reads `Foo.numbers`?

Comment: In short: no that´s not possible. Hwever I doubt that making a member of your enum is the solution to your *actual* problem. So what is that actual problem of which you think this is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could achieve this using this code:

```
public static class Numbers
{
    public static readonly int One = 1;
    public static readonly int Two = 2;
    public static readonly int Three = 3;
    internal static readonly int Zero = 0;
}
```

Additionally, it can be used exactly like `enum`.

Comment: With this method you loose some IDE features. Like completeness of values in a switch, the possibility of iterating over each value with Enum class, the type binding in a Web context, ...

Beside that even an inexistant value can be cast into an enum `var zero = (Numbers)0;`

Comment: @luc.chante Of course, but enum is not appropriate for this, so this is alternative. I am not saying it's perfect.